# WordPress: visual editor widget does not work in the footer

Tags: wordpress, editor

When I work in the visual editor widget in the footer, an error message is shown on the top and I can't save my work. This problem appears when I tried to create a footer for English version and French version.

(plugin: Black Studio TinyMCE Widget)

Comment: ... What does the error message says?

Comment: an error occurred please reload your page and retry

Comment: It seems like a javascript error, you should try to update the widget plugin if it's outdated. Maybe check on the others plugin who make changes on TinyMCE.